# Useing a link to call a delete method in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net, entity-framework, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I understand that deleting data with an http GET is a security hole. Is it also the case that calling delete from a link in general is a bad idea? I'm referring specifically to an asp.net mvc actionlink that specifies the http method as a POST.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
"DeleteNote", new { noteid = Model.noteid },
new AjaxOptions
{
    Confirm = "Delete?",
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "postmessage('note_Deleted_" + Model.noteid + "')"
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using HTTP GET is not a security hole, but could be considered bad design for a RESTful API. The convention is to use HTTP DELETE for deletion of resources.  The security hole is if your API does not support any authentication/authorization, whether it is a GET, DELETE, POST or PUT.  Then anybody with a web browser or tool like Fiddler could manipulate data they should not have access to. Take a look at this [article that describes how to use a customized Authorize attribute to secure a Web API](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/mixing-forms-authentication-basic.html).

You can still use a link to invoke your API but do not use a direct link that defines an href to the URL for delete. Instead define your anchor like this with an id.

```
<a href="#" id="aDeleteNote">Delete</a>
```

Then define a click event that calls a Javascript function that makes a secure ajax call to your API as described in the previously mentioned article.

```
$('aDeleteNote').click(DeleteNoteFunc);
```

If you want to use Razor to specify the *noteid* used to identify what to delete then you can put it in a hidden field our a Javascript variable that the *DeleteNoteFunc* has access to.

Answer (score 2):

What you're touching on here is a vulnerability called [Cross Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

A quick example of this would be as follows.

1. You have a GET link on your website, e.g. "`www.example.com/notes/delete/232`"
2. A user is logged into your website with permissions to delete note 232.
3. The user receives an email from the attacker that entices them to visit the attacker's website.
4. The user visits the website in the email, but one of the image tags is defined as follows: "`<img src="http://www.example.com/notes/delete/232" width="0" height="0" />`"

This causes the browser to make a HTTP request to your website, sending the correct authentication cookies which will result in the note being deleted without the user's knowledge.

Now this is not a vulnerability in the GET itself, but it is one of the reasons why methods such as GET should not be used to make changes on the server.

Yes you are correct you should use POST for this. POST would still be vulnerable to an attack similar to the above but the attacker would either need to create a standard HTML form to POST the data, or would have to create the POST via AJAX. If you pass the HTTP header "`X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`" and check this in your server method this will help prevent this attack as this header cannot be added to a cross domain request.

If you want to further secure this then you should implement the [Synchroniser Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) which will validate a token as part of the POST request to ensure the request came from your own site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'd describe deleting data from a GET request as necessarily a security hole (provided your application implements proper security), but it's often not a great idea as you know.

If you have delete links, you should definitely put nofollow on them, but I don't think that links which delete data are inherently bad. Even if you have no link in your markup, you still end up making an http request to a url that will delete something, either through a form submission or ajax.